# how to create 2 swipe tabs in fragment?

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, swipe

Hi guys, I have a very big problem and I really don't know where I were wrong.

my app contains Navigation Drawer menu and i need to create swipe tabs in fragments_accounts.xml

Navigation Drawer Menu contains "Accounts" when it's clicked fragments_accounts.xml will show and i wanna create 2 swipe tabs in it.

I changed import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; to import android.app.Fragment; in both of the AccountsFtagmets.java and MainActivity.java

This error will show:

> Error:(88, 28) error: incompatible types: AccountsFragment cannot be
>   converted to Fragment

How can i rescue from this error??
it's killing me!!!

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.adapter.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragments_accounts.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

there is AccountsFtagmets.java:

```
import com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.R;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



/**
 * Created by Salar on 24/4/2015.
 */
public class AccountsFragment extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public static AccountsFragment newInstance() {
        return new AccountsFragment();
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accounts, container, false);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
        // parent.
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
        // user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
                // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
                // Tab.
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
            // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // listener for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    /**
     * A {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
                    // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.
                    return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();

                default:
                    // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
                    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    return fragment;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Section " + (position + 1);
        }
    }


    /**
     * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
     */
    public static class LaunchpadSectionFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accounts_activity, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chart_activity, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public AccountsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        TextView date= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateAndTime);
        date.setText(currentDateTimeString);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_search){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new AccountsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_accounts);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AccountsFragment` needs to extend `Fragment` not `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: thank you @Rene Juuse but when I change the `FragmentActivity` to `Fragment` these 2 errors will appear:
in this line `mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());` said cannot resole method  getSupportFragmentManager()
in this line `final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` said cannot resole method getActionBar()

what should i do know?

Comment: Try calling `mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getActitvity().getSupportFragmentManager());` and `final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();` instead.

Comment: Thank you again @Rene Juuse the actionbar is correct but `mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());` is now working and said cannot resole method getActitvity()

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know why it cannot resolve the `getActivity()` method, since `Fragment` [clearly has it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29).